# string manipulation in matrix in R

Tags: r, string, matrix, data-manipulation

I have a matrix like so

```
A = matrix( 
 c("2 (1-3)", "4 (2-6)", "3 (2-4)", "1 (0.5-1.5)", "5 (2.5-7.5)", "7 (5-9)"), 
nrow=3, 
ncol=2)
```

I want to replace all strings where the first element is less than 5 (ie "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4") with "< 5". It should be:

```
B = matrix( 
  c("< 5", "< 5", "< 5", "< 5", "5 (2.5-7.5)", "7 (5-9)"), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the 1st number, convert it into numeric and replace the numbers which are less than 5 with `"<5"`.

```
A[as.numeric(sub('(\\d+).*', '\\1', A)) < 5] <- '< 5'
A

#      [,1]  [,2]         
#[1,] "< 5" "< 5"        
#[2,] "< 5" "5 (2.5-7.5)"
#[3,] "< 5" "7 (5-9)"
```

---

A shortcut to extract the first number and to convert it to numeric is using `readr::parse_number`.

```
A[readr::parse_number(A) < 5] <- '< 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substr() to etract the 1st chcaracter of each matrix element. As long as that is a number you can convert it to one via as.numeric()

```
A[as.numeric(substr(A,1,1))<5] <- "<5"
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) read.table**

Use `read.table` to get the first number in each cell giving vector `firstNo`.  Then use `replace` to replace those cells with `< 5`.

The original input `A` is preserved which is generally desirable to make it easier to test and debug but if you prefer to overwrite it anyways then replace the left hand side of the second line of code with `A`.

No regular expressions and no packages are used.

```
firstNo <- read.table(text = A)[[1]]
B <- replace(A, firstNo < 5, "< 5")

B
```

giving:

```
     [,1]  [,2]         
[1,] "< 5" "< 5"        
[2,] "< 5" "5 (2.5-7.5)"
[3,] "< 5" "7 (5-9)"
```

Although not needed for the sample input in the question, if it is possible that the text after the left parenthesis is irregular then you might need to add the `fill=TRUE` or `comment.char = "("` arguments to `read.table`.

**2) gsubfn**

`gsubfn` is like `gsub` except it inputs the capture groups in the regular expression, i.e. the parenthesized portions of the regular expression, into the function expressed in formula notation in the second argument and then replaces the match with the output of the function.

```
library(gsubfn)

B <-  replace(A, 
  TRUE, 
  gsubfn("^(\\d) (.*)", ~ if (as.numeric(x) < 5) "< 5" else paste(x, y), A)
)

B
```

giving:

```
     [,1]  [,2]         
[1,] "< 5" "< 5"        
[2,] "< 5" "5 (2.5-7.5)"
[3,] "< 5" "7 (5-9)"
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to extract and convert to numeric if there are only 5 options:

> ie "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4"

```
A[grep("^[0-4]", A)] <- "< 5"
```

Or

```
replace(A, grep("^[0-4]", A), "< 5")
```

Or

```
replace(A, startsWith("[0-4]", A), "< 5")
```

Result

```
#      [,1]  [,2]         
# [1,] "< 5" "< 5"        
# [2,] "< 5" "5 (2.5-7.5)"
# [3,] "< 5" "7 (5-9)"
```